# wrong video resolution with AMD HD7560D and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have a computer with AMD A8-5600K APU which includes the GPU HD7560D.
I use a VGA monitor with max resolution of 1280x1024.

Then I updated ubuntu to 16.04, unaware of the documented decision to drop support for fglrx drivers.

Anyway I don't need gaming features or fancy graphics, just my full resolution back. After the update instead, I get max 1024x768 and I had to put nomodeset (or radeon.modeset=0) as kernel parameters.

Then, I wanted to know if radeon, ati or amdgpu are the correct drivers to use. I couldn't find a clear documentation. Here the GPU spec:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7560D]
```

Anybody knows which driver should I use ?

And how to get a full resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the boot resolution in

> /etc/default/grub

under `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024`. Remember to `sudo update-grub` to get the settings fixed to the boot process.

I found this to be the only thing that helped with my AMD-A10-APU system. For the time being the drivers that are installed by default work fine for me, though the performance may be different for you.